# Game Center authentication error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, game-center

I'm trying to call the authentication method of game center, however no authentication screen comes up and the callback return with an error : "the requested operation has been canceled".

The code :

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
     {
        NSDictionary *userInfo = nil;
        if (error == nil) {

            NSLog(@"Game Center successfully authenticated");
        }
        else {
            userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:error forKey:@"NSError"];
        }
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:Notification
                                                            object:self
                                                          userInfo:userInfo];

    }];
```

Any idea what can cause this issue ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In iOS 4.2 when a user cancels the login to Game Center, after 3 attempts that error is returned. You can resolve the error by logging in using the Game Center app, then try your app again, you should see the welcome back message from Game Center in your app

Comment: Yes, that's what I found out as well.

Comment: btw, I noticed the "welcome back" message i popping regardless of me calling any game center function.

Comment: Is that something built in game center, noticing my app is using or configured (through itunes connect) to use game center, and then to pop that alert when I return my app to the foreground ?

Comment: Some of you might be having problems with getting locked out of Sandbox Mode for Game Center in iOS 7.0. If you end up locking yourself out after canceling the Game Center login 3 times, you can always go into Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset All Settings. It will Reset all of your settings, but you will also be allowed back into Sandbox Mode. I wish I had seen this here.

Answer (score -1):

You should do something like that after you have tested if game center is available on the specific device:

```
GKLocalPlayer *localplayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
[localplayer authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        //DISABLE GAME CENTER FEATURES / SINGLEPLAYER
    }
    else {
        //ENABLE GAME CENTER FEATURES / MULTIPLAYER
    }
}];
```

Comment: I test it prior of course , and I can't see how's your code is any different then mine.