# How to show leaderboard?

Tags: xcode, xcode6, app-store-connect, leaderboard, game-center-leaderboard

I can't find how to show leaderboard in my app.

I have leaderboard ID in the iTunes Connect.
I tried a few things but I got always the message "Player is not signed in".

Can someone please help me understand how to show the leaderboard with Objective-C?

Thanks.

Edit:
I think I know how to show the leaderboard but I can test it because I don't know how to sign in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting that error, it may not necessarily be a leaderboard problem, it means you're not signed into Game Center on your device (or simulator). I'm not sure which on you're using but you can sign in by going into settings, and going into the game center tab and signing in with your apple id or by logging into the game center app directly. You can also refer to this entry if this does not work: [SO: Game Center Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386321/game-center-authentication-error/4420457#4420457)

Comment: I'm very surprised to see that this was the problem. I was sure I logged :)  Thank You!      And by the way, I have to make leaderboard ID difficult in terms of security? (This is my first time)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "difficult in terms of security". You can just create the leaderboard ID in iTunes Connect and use that to reference that particular leaderboard. It this answer helped you, feel free to click the checkmark to accept :)

Comment: If others will know my leaderboard ID they will can to create another app that send score to my leaderboard ID? (Really sorry for my English)

Comment: The leaderboard can only been seen by logging into iTunes Connect from your account. No one in the public can see it, they simply see the name of the leaderboard (not the ID). If you want to make it secure, you can give it a name that no one could guess and make sure no one has access to your iTunes Connect info or Apple ID. Oh, and if you only have one leaderboard, that's the default leaderboard for your game by the way.